# Approximate string matching using backtracking

Tags: algorithm, string-matching, backtracking

I would like to use backtracking to search for all substrings in a long string allowing for variable length matches - that is matches allowing for a maximum given number of mismatches, insertions, and deletions. I have not been able to locate any useful examples. The closest I have found is this paper [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/Grad/scholarlypapers/papers/ghodsi.pdf), but that is terribly complex. Anyone?

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: Note. Thanks for alternative suggestions, but please show me some elegant backtracking code too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Algorithm

The function `ff()` below uses recursion (i.e. backtracking) to solve your problem.  The basic idea is that at the start of any call to `f()`, we are trying to match a suffix `t` of the original "needle" string to a suffix `s` of the "haystack" string, while allowing only a certain number of each type of edit operation.

```
// ss is the start of the haystack, used only for reporting the match endpoints.
void f(char* ss, char* s, char* t, int mm, int ins, int del) {
    while (*s && *s == *t) ++s, ++t;    // OK to always match longest segment
    if (!*t) printf("%d\n", s - ss);    // Matched; print endpoint of match
    if (mm && *s && *t) f(ss, s + 1, t + 1, mm - 1, ins, del);
    if (ins && *s) f(ss, s + 1, t, mm, ins - 1, del);
    if (del && *t) f(ss, s, t + 1, mm, ins, del - 1);
}

// Find all occurrences of t starting at any position in s, with at most
// mm mismatches, ins insertions and del deletions.
void ff(char* s, char* t, int mm, int ins, int del) {
    for (char* ss = s; *s; ++s) {
//      printf("Starting from offset %d...\n", s - ss);
        f(ss, s, t, mm, ins, del);
    }
}
```

Example call:

```
ff("xxabcydef", "abcdefg", 1, 1, 1);
```

This outputs:

```
9
9
```

because there are two ways to find "abcdefg" in "xxabcydef" with at most 1 of each kind of change, and both of these ways end at position 9:

```
Haystack: xxabcydef-
Needle:     abc-defg
```

which has 1 insertion (of `y`) and 1 deletion (of `g`), and

```
Haystack: xxabcyde-f
Needle:     abc-defg
```

which has 1 insertion (of `y`), 1 deletion (of `f`), and 1 substitution of `g` to `f`.

### Dominance Relation

It may not be obvious why it's actually safe to use the `while` loop on line 3 to greedily match as many characters as possible at the start of the two strings.  In fact this may reduce the number of *times* that a particular end position will be reported as a match, but it will never cause an end position to be forgotten completely -- and since we're usually interested in just whether or not there is a match ending at a given position of the haystack, and without this `while` loop the algorithm would *always* take time exponential in the needle size, this seems a win-win.

It is guaranteed to work because of a *dominance relation*.  To see this, suppose the opposite -- that it is in fact unsafe (i.e. misses some matches).  Then there would be some match in which an initial segment of equal characters from both strings are not aligned to each other, for example:

```
Haystack: abbbbc
Needle:   a-b-bc
```

However, any such match can be transformed into another match having the same number of operations of each type, and ending at the same position, by shunting the leftmost character following a gap to the left of the gap:

```
Haystack: abbbbc
Needle:   ab--bc
```

If you do this repeatedly until it's no longer possible to shunt characters without requiring a substitution, you will get a match in which the largest initial segment of equal characters from both strings are aligned to each other:

```
Haystack: abbbbc
Needle:   abb--c
```

My algorithm will find all such matches, so it follows that no match position will be overlooked by it.

### Exponential Time

Like any backtracking program, this function will exhibit exponential slowdowns on certain inputs.  Of course, it may be that on the inputs you happen to use, this doesn't occur, and it works out faster than particular implementations of DP algorithms.

Comment: Nope, just on a few examples until it seemed to work.  `f()` is simple enough that it should be possible to prove that it works by thinking about all possible combinations of s and t inputs: (a) s is empty, t isn't; (b) t is empty, s isn't; (c) both are empty; (d) neither is empty and they start with 1 or more equal characters; (e) neither is empty and they start with different characters.  Notice that case (d) is converted to one of the other cases by the `while` loop, which simplifies things further.

Comment: You keep saying that scan_for_matches "is faster" than other things, but you don't give the examples (needle, haystack, #mm, #ins, #del) you're actually testing on -- do you realise the speed depends entirely on that?

Comment: I can think of a few ways to speed it up without losing any "important" matches.  One is that an insertion followed immediately by a deletion (or vice versa) can always be replaced by a single substitution if `mm > 0`, since if we require that substitution later on in the same match we can just use the insertion+deletion combo instead (since, having "saved" 1 of each, we still have at least one of each to "spend").  This translates to forbidding an ins following a del and vice versa whenever `mm > 0`.

Comment: Also we can require that any contiguous block of insertions and deletions contains (say) all insertions first -- this translates to forbidding an insertion following a deletion, full stop.  Finally, because `ff()` starts from each position in turn, we aren't much interested in matches that begin with one or more insertions (since they will all be found by `ff()` using later calls to `f()`), so `f()` could take an extra parameter, `allow_ins`, telling it whether to try insertions.  `ff()` would pass 0 for this, while all recursive calls of `f()` would pass 1 for the usual behaviour.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hr7y3gz1 fixes your bug.  The problem was that on lines 14-16 you were returning right away, so for example if it was possible to try a mutation at a given position (i.e. if line 14's `if` condition was satisfied) then no insertion or deletion would be tried at that position.  If the mutation later forced a mismatch, but (say) a deletion would have allowed a match, this match would be missed.

Comment: Me bad (again) - I was trying to reverse the meaning of ins and del and screwed up. I have written unit tests for all edge cases and it looks good. Also, I groomed my own comments here since this is not a discussion forum - I suggest you do the same. Thanks again for the assistance! My implementation is here: http://code.google.com/p/biopieces/source/browse/trunk/code_ruby/lib/maasha/backtrack.rb

Comment: No problem :) But out of interest, I thought you were interested in speed, and Ruby is a slow interpreted language...?

Comment: It is a trade-off. Ruby for flexibility and Inline-C for speed.

Comment: Ah, good idea. Thanks for mentioning me in the comments; it would be even better if you gave the URL of this SO question.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with [Levenshtein's distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm, which is the standard approach when checking for string similarities via mismatch, insertion and deletion.

Since the algorithm uses [bottom up dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), you'll probably be able to find all substrings without having to execute the algorithm for each potential substring.

Comment: Thanks, but I am explicitly interested in how to use backtracking for this.

Comment: Ok, ic. But if you are interested in String distances, I'd stick to dynamic programming. If you are interested in backtracking, I'd find a more suitable problem. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: With respect to biological sequence pattern matching scan_for_matches http://blog.theseed.org/servers/2010/07/scan-for-matches.html outperforms all dynamic programming software AFAIK. scan_for_matches is based on backtracking.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that - I wouldn't have guessed.

Comment: @maasha: Backtracking-based approximate string search takes time exponential in the pattern length in the worst case -- e.g. if you try to match the pattern "abcd" against the text "aabbcce" with at most 3 insertions or deletions, each of the 2^3=8 ways of deleting each of a, b and c must be tried all the way through to the "c != e" comparison, even though the that final comparison means the final answer is "no match".  scan-for-matches may be faster on the non-pathological cases you've tried, which is fine, but it's slower in the worst case than DP algorithms.

Comment: The implementations of DP I tried http://www.logic.at/people/bruno/Papers/2007-GATE-ESSLLI.pdf (page 200 ff) encounters problems if you want to specify mismatches/insertions/deletions since some combinations of these will never be considered, and you will not get an exhaustive result.

Answer (score 0):

The nicest algorithm I'm aware of for this is [A Fast Bit-Vector Algorithm for Approximate String Matching Based on Dynamic Programming](http://www.gersteinlab.org/courses/452/09-spring/pdf/Myers.pdf) by Gene Myers.  Given a text to search of length n, a pattern string to search for of length m and a maximum number of mismatches/insertions/deletions k, this algorithm takes time O(mn/w), where w is your computer's word size (32 or 64).  If you know much about algorithms on strings, it's actually pretty incredible that an algorithm exists that takes time independent of k -- for a long time, this seemed an impossible goal.

I'm not aware of an existing implementation of the above algorithm.  If you want a tool, [`agrep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrep) may be just what you need.  It uses an earlier algorithm that takes time O(mnk/w), but it's fast enough for low k -- miles ahead of a backtracking search in the worst case.

`agrep` is based on the [Shift-Or (or "Bitap") algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitap_algorithm), which is a very clever dynamic programming algorithm that manages to represent its state as bits in an integer and get *binary addition* to do most of the work of updating the state, which is what speeds up the algorithm by a factor of 32 or 64 over a more typical implementation.  :)  Myers's algorithm also uses this idea to get its 1/w speed factor.

Comment: I tested nrgrep - which is in part an implementation of bitap - against scan_for_mathches - and scan_for_matches win (see other comment). Also, the different implementations (agrep, nrgrep, etc.) don't allow you to specify the number of mismathes, insertions and deletions, but rather an edit distance.

Comment: That Gene Myers paper is also terribly complex. I really need to see a walkthrough example and some easy prototype code.